# Bootstrap nav-tabs When URL content à id (#/mypage/:id)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap `nav-tabs`. With the example below I have no problem if the page's URL is `mypage`

```
($stateProvider.state('ide', {url: '/mypage',...)
```

but I must have an id parameter

```
($stateProvider.state('ide', {url: '/mypage/:id',...)
```

that no longer works. I am redirected to the homepage of the site . Do you know how to change my code to make it work?

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="active tab-pane fade in" id="tab1">
            <div id="editorA"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
            <div id="editorB"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab3">
            <div id="editorC"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My link go to http://localhost:8080/#/mypage#tab2 instead of http://localhost:8080/#/mypage/1063#tab2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

**In my AngularJS controller I add:**

```
$scope.keepId=id;
```

**In my HTML page, I add #/mypage/{{keepId}} in link:**

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#/mypage/{{keepId}}#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#/mypage/{{keepId}}#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#/mypage/{{keepId}}#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="active tab-pane fade in" id="tab1">
            <div id="editorA"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
            <div id="editorB"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab3">
            <div id="editorC"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```